# How to check if variable is integer (avoid problem with spaces around) in POSIX shell script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, posix

My POSIX `is_integer ()` function looks like this for a long time:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
is_integer ()
{
    [ "$1" -eq "$1" ] 2> /dev/null
}
```

However, today, I found it *broken*. If there are some spaces around the number, it surprisingly also evaluates to `true`, and I have no idea how to fix that.

---

Example of correct (expected) behavior:

`is_integer 123` evaluates to `true`.

Example of incorrect (unexpected) behavior:

**`is_integer ' 123'` also evaluates to `true`**, however it obviously contains a leading space, thus the function is expected to evaluate to `false` in such cases.

---

POSIX-compliant suggestions only, please. Thank you.

Comment: Note that even in the absence of spaces, you couldn't use that to detect integers in ksh, since extends the interpretation of the arguments of `-eq` quite a lot wider than to just integers. Stuff like `abc` (the value on variable `abc`), `12.345` (floating point), `1+1` (arithmetic expression) get accepted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
is_integer ()
{
    case "${1#[+-]}" in
        (*[!0123456789]*) return 1 ;;
        ('')              return 1 ;;
        (*)               return 0 ;;
    esac
}
```

Uses only POSIX builtins.
It is not clear from the spec if `+1` is supposed to be an integer, if not then remove the `+` from the `case` line.

It works as follows. the `${1#[+-]}` removes the optional leading sign. If you are left with something containing a non digit then it is not an integer, likewise if you are left with nothing. If it is not not an integer then it is an integer.

Edit: change ^ to ! to negate the character class - thanks @LinuxSecurityFreak

Comment: I don't get why ^ was changed to !. Isn't ^ used to negate the class? See [RE bracket expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)

Comment: True! Just for the record, here the exception is documented in [Shell Command Language, Pattern Matching Notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01).

Comment: Your tests should have some multi-digit strings in them. You might want to extend the patterns to reject leading zeros (accept '0', reject '0'*).

Comment: @icarus.   You can replace `[!0123456789]` with a POSIX class, i.e. `[![:digit:]]`

Comment: @fpmurphy That is true that you can use [:digit:] but I would rather not have 123๔ as an integer because the last character is a digit 4 in Thai. In the original version of this post I use `[^0-9]` but changed it to explicitly list the characters I wanted to use in the definition of an integer.

Comment: @icarus.  AFAIK, the last 'glyph' in your example will only be recognized as a digit if your locale is set to `th_TH`, `th_TH.utf8`, `th_TH.tis620`, etc.  Are you saying it will be recognized as a digit in other locales such as `en_US.UTF-8`?

Comment: @fpmurphy No, I don't think so. You see, probably `[:digit:]` is locale dependent. That's what I think he was trying to say.

Comment: @fpmurphy, on some BSDs, `[[:digit:]]` will match all decimal digits, not just the Arabic / ASCII ones, even in US English locales.

Comment: Nice answer. Sometime I am a fan of one-liner. Based on this answer, I use parameter expansion. `if [ -n "$var" ] && [ "$var" = "${var#*[!0123456789]}" ] ; then printf 'Yes.\n' ; else printf 'No.\n' ; fi`

Comment: @midnite One liners can be great, but sometimes can be taken too far. For something in a script I think `if is_integer "$var" ; then` is short and readable. Your code needs another clause to strip off a leading minus sign in order for "-1" to be an integer, but "23-1" not to be one.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient (due to the external command), but quite simple:

```
is_integer () {
  expr "X$1" : "X-\{0,1\}[0-9][0-9]*$" > /dev/null
}
```

At least in the implementation I am testing, an initial argument `-` is treated not as part of a matching operation, but apparently as part of an invalid arithmetic expression; the `X` ensures `expr` parses its arguments as a valid match operation.

Comment: Don't use `[0-9]` for input validation, it often matches thousands of characters some of which can cause nasty problems if not filtered out. Use `[0123456789]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain if octal and hexadecimal support is is available in POSIX `sh`, but it is in busybox `ash`.  In this case, a more complete solution would be as follows:

```bsh
is_integer() {
    local n=${1#[-+]}
    case "$n" in
        0[0-7]*) case "$n" in 0*[!0-7]*)                 return 1;; esac;;
        0[xX]*)  case "$n" in 0[xX]|0[xX]*[!0-9a-fA-F]*) return 1;; esac;;
        *)       case "$n" in ''|*[!0-9]*)               return 1;; esac;;
    esac
}
```

This strips any leading sign and then parses the string depending upon rather or not it has a prefix of `0`, `0x` or `0X`.  Thus, one should be aware not to have arbitrary leading zeros on a value that will be used as decimal number.

```bsh
$ echo $((01))
1
$ echo $((08))
-ash: arithmetic syntax error
```

Comment: Don't use ranges like `[0-7]` for input validation! They often match thousands of characters some of which can cause nasty problems if not ruled out. Use `[01234567]`. Note that `local` is not POSIX.

Comment: Octal and hexadecimal are allowed in POSIX sh arithmetic expressions or in POSIX `printf %d` arguments, not in `[`'s `-eq` operand, but then again leading blanks are allowed in most of those as well. The OP didn't specify where the numbers were going to be used after being sanitised.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hello.  I would be most interested to learn about how `[0-7]` could possibly match other characters. Can you post a link?  Thank you for the clarification on octal and hex in POSIX `sh`!  I wasn't able to immediately find it in the spec.

Comment: See for instance [How to ensure user input consists of exactly 6 digits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608965) or [Rename special characters in filenames to underscore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/620729) or [regex pattern issue for digit validation in ksh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/654372) for instance here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Those aren't sources, those are links to you making similar comments. I've tried to reproduce the incorrect matching, but of the ~1000 characters that would supposedly match incorrectly, I cannot get a single match in any shell or regex implementation I've tried. Do you have a specific reproducible example in which the matching goes wrong?

Comment: @FWDekker try for instance `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 bash -c '[[ ۸ = [0-9] ]] && echo yes'` on Ubuntu 22.04 for instance (same with the 1000+ other characters mentioned in those other questions). YMMV with the tool, libc, OSes and versions thereof.