# How to ensure user input consists of exactly 6 digits

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, pattern-matching

I am running HP-UX 11.23 and have a bash script that reads two inputs.

Both inputs need to be exactly 6 digits long.

What is the best way to read the input and if its not 6 numbers
ask the users to try again ?

```
echo "Enter the 6 digit missing file numbers"
echo "You don't need to put USSR or .txt.got"
echo
echo "If you just have one file, enter the same number twice"
echo
echo "e.g 230123"
echo " 230130"
echo
echo "Enter the first file name"
read file1
while [ -z "$file1" ]; do
    echo "The first file name is incorrect"
    echo "Please enter 6 digit number again"
    read file1
done
echo
echo "Enter second file name"
read file2
while [ -z "$file2" ]; do
    echo "The last file name is incorrect"
    echo "Please enter 6 digit number again"
    read file2
done
if [ $file1 -le $file2 ]
then
    echo "Sequence numbers look OK" 
fi
```

Comment: Do you explicitly want a "6-digit number" in the usual sense -- i.e. `003142` is not acceptable? How about `-123456` or `+123456`.  You need two tests: is it 6 long `[[ "${#num}" -eq 6 ]]` and is it numeric with a RE. Or a RE that explicitly repeats six `[0-9]` instances.

Comment: just 6 digits, no plus or minus.

Comment: This is helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/598036

Comment: What scripting language are you using? What do you have so far? Please [edit] your question and show us your script and specify the language you are using so we don't waste your time with answers that won't help you.

Comment: Steve, please don't put updates to your question here in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question and put them there so everyone can easily find them

Answer (score 4):

```
valid() {
  local d='[0123456789]'
  case $1 in
    ($d$d$d$d$d$d) true;;
    (*) false;;
  esac
}

# or:

valid() {
  # note that it clobbers $BASH_REMATCH even if you declare
  # it locally to the function.
  local re='^[0123456789]{6}$'
  [[ $1 =~ $re ]]
}

until
  IFS= read -rp 'First file: ' file1 || exit
  valid "$file1"
do
  echo >&2 Invalid, try again.
done
```

Do not use `[0-9]` in place of `[0123456789]` unless you're OK for it to also match on characters such as `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈०१२३४५६७८০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౸౹౺౻౼౽౾೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮෦෧෨෩෪෫෬෭෮๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༪༫༬༭༮༯༰༱༳၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘፩፪፫፬፭፮፯፰០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៰៱៲៳៴៵៶៷៸᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧚᪀᪁᪂᪃᪄᪅᪆᪇᪈᪐᪑᪒᪓᪔᪕᪖᪗᪘᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘⁰⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞⅟ↅ↉①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳⑴⑵⑶⑷⑸⑹⑺⑻⑽⑾⑿⒀⒁⒂⒃⒄⒅⒆⒇⒈⒉⒊⒋⒌⒍⒎⒏⒑⒒⒓⒔⒕⒖⒗⒘⒙⒚⒛⓪⓫⓬⓭⓮⓯⓰⓱⓲⓳⓴⓵⓶⓷⓸⓹⓺⓻⓼⓾⓿❶❷❸❹❺❻❼❽❿➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➉➊➋➌➍➎➏➐➑➓〇〡〢〣〤〥〦〧〨㉈㉉㉊㉋㉌㉍㉎㉏㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙㉚㉛㉜㉝㉞㉟㊱㊲㊳㊴㊵㊶㊷㊸㊹㊺㊻㊼㊽㊾㊿㋀㋁㋂㋃㋄㋅㋆㋇㋉㋊㋋㍘㍙㍚㍛㍜㍝㍞㍟㍠㍢㍣㍤㍥㍦㍧㍨㍩㍪㍫㍬㍭㍮㍯㍰㏠㏡㏢㏣㏤㏥㏦㏧㏩㏪㏫㏬㏭㏮㏯㏰㏱㏲㏳㏴㏵㏶㏷㏸㏹㏺㏻㏼㏽㏾꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꧐꧑꧒꧓꧔꧕꧖꧗꧘꧰꧱꧲꧳꧴꧵꧶꧷꧸꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꯰꯱꯲꯳꯴꯵꯶꯷꯸０１２３４５６７８` depending on the locale and system.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the question itself, I've never seen the `until list-1; do...done` syntax like this before (more commonly, nor for `while`). I'd always assumed it was `until/while command1 [&&/|| command2...]; do ... done`. Thank you for teaching me something new today

Comment: @roaima same here, it is one of the reason I come and stay here (U&L), I can learn new (dirty *cough*) trick.