# Rename special characters in filenames to underscore

Tags: sed, rename

I am trying to change all characters that are not letters, numbers, dashes, dots, or underscores to an underscore in file names in a directory. So far I have the following:

```
ls *.mp3 | sed 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z._-]/_/g'
```

This works except that it just shows me the results, it does not actually change the names. What else do I need to do to get it to change the names?

Comment: You're saying *letter*, but your `a-z` suggests you only want letters in the latin script. `a-z` would typically include `é`  but not `ẑ` for instance which comes after `z`. I take it you don't want Greek/Cyrillic/Arabic/Korean... letters? What about latin letters with diacritics or followed by combining characters? What about other variants of the latin letters that don't fall in the ASCII range like , ᴀ, Ɐ, Ａ, tag letters...

Comment: Kojow7, can you please be more specific about what special characters means here? As Stéphane Chazelas has pointed out, working with multi-byte characters is tricky, but if you meant only `&*$`... by special characters, then the solution is not arduous.

Comment: @Quasímodo basically anything that is not a digit, a letter of the 26-letter English alphabet, dot, underscore, or dash. Most of the situations I am coming across include: spaces, quotes, apostrophes, and question marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't parse Ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). That seems to work well, but for complex cases it may fail.

With [Bash's parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for f in *.mp3; do mv -- "$f" "${f//[!0-9a-zA-Z.-]/_}"; done
```

With Rename:

```
rename -- 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z.-]/_/g' *.mp3
```

If you only have standard POSIX tools and assuming no newline characters in the file names,

```
for f in *.mp3; do 
    mv -- "$f" "$(printf '%s\n' "$f" | sed 's/[^0-9a-zA-Z.-]/_/g')"
done
```

Comment: Except with the `rename`-based one, you'll need `export LC_ALL=C` or otherwise those ranges could match thousands of characters beside the English letter/digits and could also fail on filenames that don't form valid text in the locale. That would however mean that if there are UTF-8 encoded non-ASCII characters in those file names, each *byte* of those characters would be converted to `_`.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of POSIX `sed` is unspecified on non-text input, like that output of `printf` not ending in a newline character. Also beware that that `sed` command won't replace newline characters in those filenames.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was thinking only of ASCII special characters (`&*$`...).  I guess replacing `0-9a-zA-Z` by `[:alnum:]` wouldn't solve the problem for ranges outside English? I hope the asker will answer to our clarification requests, meanwhile I will fix that thing with Sed. Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(*).mp3' '${f//[^0-9a-zA-Z_.-]/_}'
```

In `zsh`, ranges are based on codepoint value, so `0-9` includes 0123456789  only (and not `0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈०१२३४५६७८০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౸౹౺౻౼౽౾೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮෦෧෨෩෪෫෬෭෮๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༪༫༬༭༮༯༰༱༳၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘፩፪፫፬፭፮፯፰០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៰៱៲៳៴៵៶៷៸᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧚᪀᪁᪂᪃᪄᪅᪆᪇᪈᪐᪑᪒᪓᪔᪕᪖᪗᪘᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘⁰⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜⅝⅞⅟ↅ↉①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳⑴⑵⑶⑷⑸⑹⑺⑻⑽⑾⑿⒀⒁⒂⒃⒄⒅⒆⒇⒈⒉⒊⒋⒌⒍⒎⒏⒑⒒⒓⒔⒕⒖⒗⒘⒙⒚⒛⓪⓫⓬⓭⓮⓯⓰⓱⓲⓳⓴⓵⓶⓷⓸⓹⓺⓻⓼⓾⓿❶❷❸❹❺❻❼❽❿➀➁➂➃➄➅➆➇➉➊➋➌➍➎➏➐➑➓〇〡〢〣〤〥〦〧〨㉈㉉㉊㉋㉌㉍㉎㉏㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙㉚㉛㉜㉝㉞㉟㊱㊲㊳㊴㊵㊶㊷㊸㊹㊺㊻㊼㊽㊾㊿㋀㋁㋂㋃㋄㋅㋆㋇㋉㋊㋋㍘㍙㍚㍛㍜㍝㍞㍟㍠㍢㍣㍤㍥㍦㍧㍨㍩㍪㍫㍬㍭㍮㍯㍰㏠㏡㏢㏣㏤㏥㏦㏧㏩㏪㏫㏬㏭㏮㏯㏰㏱㏲㏳㏴㏵㏶㏷㏸㏹㏺㏻㏼㏽㏾꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꧐꧑꧒꧓꧔꧕꧖꧗꧘꧰꧱꧲꧳꧴꧵꧶꧷꧸꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꯰꯱꯲꯳꯴꯵꯶꯷꯸０１２３４５６７８` like in `bash` in most modern locales) and `a-z` only `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` (not the thousands of characters other shells would match), but that still done on a per character basis (contrary to what would happened if you switched to the C locale in `bash` to work around the previous issue where it would work on bytes and break up characters into the bytes constituting there encoding for multibyte ones).

It also doesn't choke on bytes not forming valid characters in the locale (and those bytes would match `[^0-9a-zA-Z_.-]`), so in the end, the resulting files should only contain characters among `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_.-`, and no non-character.

In `bash`, you could do something approaching with:

```
accepted_characters='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_.-'
for f in *[^$accepted_characters]*.mp3; do
  mv -i -- "$f" "${f//[^$accepted_characters]/_}"
done
```

(without the safeguards of `zmv`).