# regex pattern issue for digit validation in ksh

Tags: regular-expression

I was writing a ksh script to validate the column is numerical. The regex pattern is defined in a config file like `\d+.\d+`. But this is not working when I use `d` pattern. However `[0-9]{1,9}` is working. Any insights into this?

- Here is the ksh version I am using:

  ```
  $ ksh --version
    version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
  ```
- Code snippet for the pattern comparison. If I provide `$col_patt` as `\d+` it would not work but `[0-9]{1,}` will work

  ```
  val=$(awk -F "$sep" -v n="$col_pos" -v m="$col_patt" 'NR!=1 && $n !~ "^" m "$" {
                           printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $n > "/dev/stderr"
                           count++
                         }
                         END {print count+0}' "$cp_input" 2>> $script_path/errors_${file_name_patt}.log
                         )
  ```
- Here is the pattern used: `\d*\.\d+`

Comment: That very much depends on the tool (and implementation/version thereof) or ksh construct that is used to match strings against that pattern and the implementation and version of ksh if a ksh construct. `string=00.99 ksh -c '[[ $string = ~(E:\d+\.\d+) ]] && echo yes'` should work if using ksh93 for instance.

Comment: See also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905) (possible duplicate)

Comment: IOW, unless you tell us (by [edit]ing your question to provide the additional info) what software is trying to make use of that regexp, we can't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various utilities, languages, regex/pattern libraries and APIs support different operators/wildcards.

`\d` is a perl regex operator that matches a decimal digit (generally any of `0123456789`, but under some conditions can match other decimal digits (there are hundreds in Unicode such as 0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯෦෧෨෩෪෫෬෭෮෯๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᥏᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙᪀᪁᪂᪃᪄᪅᪆᪇᪈᪉᪐᪑᪒᪓᪔᪕᪖᪗᪘᪙᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᭙᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᮹᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱉᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꣙꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꤉꧐꧑꧒꧓꧔꧕꧖꧗꧘꧙꧰꧱꧲꧳꧴꧵꧶꧷꧸꧹꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꩙꯰꯱꯲꯳꯴꯵꯶꯷꯸꯹０１２３４５６７８９
)).

Since perl introduced that operator in the 80s, a few regexp engines have followed suit, but far from all. The ones beside `perl` that support it that I'm aware of are:

- `vim` (not inside bracket expressions).
- `PCRE` library (as used in many tools and languages)
- `python` or `ruby` regexps or more generally regular expressions that aim to cover most of or extend the PCRE ones.
- `ast-open` regexps, as used by ksh93, or the `grep` / `sed` builtins of ksh93 when ksh93 has been compiled as part of ast-open and you've run `builtin grep` / `builtin sed` or put `/opt/ast/bin` at the front of `$PATH` to enable them. In ksh93 globs, `\d` is only recognised  if found inside one of its `x(...)` extended operators (where `x` can be `@`, `+`, `~`...). `[[ 1 = @(\d) ]]` will match but not `[[ 1 = \d ]]` (not inside bracket expressions).

The POSIX equivalent in POSIX *basic* or *extended* regular expressions and shell filename patterns (as used in shell filename generation or `fnmatch()`, or `find` `-path`/`-name` patterns for instance) is `[[:digit:]]`. That's meant to be the same as `[0123456789]` but you'll find some systems where that matches other digits.

There's also `[0-9]` that matches characters that come between 0 and 9. Again, that should include `[0123456789]`  but often includes more. POSIX only guarantees `[0-9]` to be the same as `[0123456789]` in the `C` / `POSIX` locale.

`zsh` globs also support the `<x-y>` operator to match strings that represent a decimal number in the specific range. `<3-12>` for instance would match on `006`, `11`, `012`, and `<->` would be the same as `perl`'s `\d+` (though only with 0123456789 digits).

Not all regexp engines will recognise `+` either. That one comes from `egrep` / `awk` in the late 70s, and (contrary to `\d`) could not be added to already existing regexp engines (like those of `grep`, `sed` or `vi`) as that would have broken backward compatibility and scripts that were doing `grep +` to look for `+` characters for instance.

All regexp engines (not globs) recognise the `.` operator though which matches any single character (same as the `?` glob operator) as that was in the original implementation from the 60s.

The most portable regexp to match strings that is made of one or more ASCII decimal digits followed by a literal `.` followed by 1 or more ASCII decimal digits would be:

```
^[0123456789][0123456789]*[.][0123456789][0123456789]*$
```

Though note that in `perl` that would also match on `12.3<newline>` as well. You'd need `^\d+\.\d\Z` to avoid it.

Since you've now clarified the tool was `awk`, I don't know of any `awk` implementations that support `\d` as a regexp operator. All will support `[0123456789]` and `+`. All will support `[0-9]` though what it matches outside of the C locale depends on implementation, most will support `[[:digit:]]`.

Also, to pass data to `awk` that may contain backslash character (which happens to be the case for you), you should avoid `-v` as that does one level of backslash escape expansion¹ (`\n` turns into a newline character `\\` into `\` and `\d` into `\d` or `d` or generate an error depending on the implementation).

So here, you'd want:

```
val=$(
  RE="$col_patt" awk -F "$sep" -v n="$col_pos" '
    BEGIN {m = ENVIRON["RE"]}
    NR!=1 && $n !~ "^" m "$" {
      printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $n > "/dev/stderr"
      count++
    }
    END {print count+0}
    ' "$cp_input" 2>> "$script_path/errors_${file_name_patt}.log"
)
```

And make sure `$col_patt` contains a regexp compatible with the syntax recognised by your `awk` implementation.

```
col_patt='[0123456789]+\.[0123456789]'
```

at least should be OK.

---

<sup>¹ Recent versions of the GNU implementation of `awk` also has a problem with values starting with `@/` and ending in `/`. See how `awk -v var='@/x/' 'BEGIN{print var}'` outputs `x` instead of `@/x/` there</sup>